# Why is it safe to rebase under these conditions?

Tags: git, rebase

The [git documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/) mentions in several places [not to rebase if the code has been pushed to a public repository](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing#The-Perils-of-Rebasing). However, I have seen [this rebase strategy](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/07/git-tips/) suggested in multiple places while Googling my Git problems.

The situation stated is to use `git pull` with the `--rebase` option when working with other devs in order to reduce the amount of merge commits which "pollute the logs". This can even be made automatic by setting the `branch.master.rebase` option to `true`.

**Why is this strategy considered safe, seeing how the fine documentation specifically warns against rebasing when working with other devs?**

Comment: It doesn't warn against rebasing when working with others, it warns against rebasing ***commits that other people already have a copy of***. That's the difference. Rebasing changes the sha IDs for the commits, so there will be a mismatch between the commits that you've just rebased, and everyone else's old copies of them. If you're rebasing commits that you haven't shared with anyone else yet, then there's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you're misinterpreting the warning.

Say there's a local commit `A` that hasn't been pushed, and a commit `B` that hasn't been pulled. By running `git pull --rebase`, you're gonna *destroy* commit `A`, pull commit `B`, and *re-create* commit `A` on top of `B`.

Since commit `A` is local, this is fine and safe, and it's what the rebase strategy suggests. But, the documentation tells you not to do this **if** commit `A` had already been pushed (to a different branch, for example). In that case, you'd be destroying a publicly available commit, and re-writing public history.

Answer (score 5):

When you do a `git pull --rebase` you don't push anything anywhere. So it's safe.

With a normal `git pull`, the following happens:

```
A-B-C(master)
   \
    D(origin/master)

becomes

A-B-C-E(master)
   \ /
    D(origin/master)
```

Which is "polluted" with a merge commit.

If you use `git pull --rebase` instead:

```
A-B-C(master)
   \
    D(origin/master)

becomes

A-B-D(origin/master)
     \
      E(master)
```

No merge, more linear history. Still no push, no danger. You've only rewritten the history of your local `master` branch.

The very reason that `master` and `origin/master` have diverged, is that you have not pushed your `master` yet. That's why there is no contradiction with all the warnings about using rebase.

Comment: This doesn't explain the apparent contradiction between the warnings in the documentation and the core of the rebase strategy

Comment: The very reason that `master` and `origin/master` have diverged is that you have not pushed your `master` yet. That's why there is no contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

## Why People Don't Like to Rebase Public Commits

People usually don't want to rebase commits that are shared with other people because it makes it harder for them to sync their old commits with the rewritten commits that result from the rebase.

Note that **this does not mean that it's impossible** for team members to sync their work with publicly pushed code that has been rebased. ***It's just harder to coordinate, especially for large teams***. If you have to sync your work that's based off of old public commits with the same rebased commits, then you can use the `git rebase --onto` flag to do it. [The official Linux Kernel git documentation for `rebase`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html#_the_hard_case) even states so.

So basically, if you don't trust other people to be able to or know how to sync their work with rebased public commits, or you don't want to create extra work for other developers, ***don't push rebased commits that have already been publicly pushed***.

## Why It's OK to Rebase Local Unshared Commits

Notice, however, that I said ***already publicly pushed***. If no one else has a copy of the commits that you're going to rebase, then there's nothing to worry about. **That's why it's okay to use `git pull --rebase` on your own local commits**...as long as you've never shared those local commits with anyone else yet.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a pull --rebase, you rebase your commits on top of whats on the remote.

What you indeed shouldn't do is rebase your own commits (interactive), for commits which you've already pushed to the master.

If you do an interactive rebase, e.g. you squash your own commits, for commits already pushed to the master, you are actually "destroying" the history of your git repository. Most git servers will not allow you to push those commits to the remote anyway.

So be aware that the one they are warning you for is something totally different than doing a pull --rebase